# Start Activity after put widget on screen

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I was stuck with a problem:
I want to start ChooseWidgetActivity after put widget on screen.

I coded onUpdate in WidgetProvider like that:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        //--- I'm starting activity here:
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetChooseActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        //---

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout_icon);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetIcon, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
```

But only what I get is WidgetChooseActivity that starts immediately after choose widget from widgets screen. I can't put it on screen because my activity overshadowing android main screen.
Is it possible to start activity **after** put widget on screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some time ago I came up with a solution to my problem ... To start some activity **after** put widget on screen, it's enough to define it in the manifest with special intent-filter, for example:

```
<activity android:name=".MyWidgetConfigurationActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and add **android:configure** entry in AppWidgetProviderInfo metadata, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:configure=".MyWidgetConfigurationActivity"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="30000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can use a handler for this .

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(); 

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
             public void run() {  


                 try {
                    // here write down the code  

                }  catch (ExecutionException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

             }  
        }, 2000);
```

Comment: Is it correct answer? I think he wants to delay showing `Activity` until user place item on screen (like Gmail widget) - not delay it because then we have strange action if user holds widget too long and `Activity` appears out of nowhere.

Comment: @jeet It's not completely solve my problem, because user always has specified time to put widget on main screen. If this time is up and user still holds widget - myActivity's overshadowing main screen and placing widget on it becomes impossible..